# How to get all 365 users emails in my organization by SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, cascading-dropdown

Is it possible to get all the e-mails in my organization and put them in a SharePoint Dropdown List. So let's say i have a group of customer service team that have 50 emails so instead of writing again all emails how can i merge them into a dropdown ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can request all users from your organization with Graph API:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

And then populate the drop-down with their e-mail addresses.